# How to return a refrence from a function with making copy

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a function which return `value` if a `key` exist in `map` like:

```
map<int,string> mymap;
//Assume there are some key value pair in above map

string & ReturnKey(int &a)
{
    string ret;
    map<int,string>::iterator iter = mymap.find(a);
    if(iter not_eq mymap.end())
    {
        ret = iter->second;//I think this will make copy
    }
    else
    return ret;
}
```

How can I avoid copy of string which is returning from above function?

Comment: `return iter->second;`

Comment: @BrianBi what if it is not found ?

Comment: copying an empty string costs almost nothing

Comment: @BrianBi Thanks, so its a good practice to write function like above where if a key is not found then return an empty object.

Comment: Actually, you should never return a reference to a local variable like that, because the local variable gets destroyed as soon as the function finishes executing.

Comment: So how should I write above function?

Comment: You have a few options. You can change the return type to `std::string` and you can have the function return copies. You can insert an empty string into the map and return a reference to that (this is what `std::map::operator[]` does). Or, you can keep returning references, but throw an exception if the key isn't found (this is what `std::map::at` does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with the returned reference being const, you can do something like this:

```
const string & ReturnKey(int a)
{
  static const string defaultValue;  // to be returned if object isn't found
  map<int,string>::iterator iter = mymap.find(a);
  if(iter != mymap.end())
  {
     return iter->second;
  }
  else return defaultValue;
```

}

It's safe to return a reference to (defaultValue) in the not-found case because defaultValue is declared static and therefore will still exist after the function returns.  In the value-found case, the caller will need to be careful not to hold the reference and try to use it after mymap has been cleared or modified, but that's usually not an issue in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a reference to an existing string or raise an exception if it doesn't exist. This is easily done with the [`std::map::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) method:

```
string& ReturnKey(int a)
{
  return mymap.at(a);
}
```

If you are stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler, you have to do it by hand:

```
string& ReturnKey(int a)
{
  map<int,string>::iterator iter = mymap.find(a);
  if(iter == mymap.end())
    throw std::out_of_range("Invalid key");
  return iter->second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in your program you **can not return the reference** of the variable declared inside the function because as the function complete the execution all the variable declared inside that function will get released and deleted.

So in  that case you will get `null` or `garbage value` every time the function will called.

For this In my opinion you can `pass your string argument as a reference` in the function.
so, by using this you can get your desired value in your variable.

Or
 You can also change the return type of the function to `std::string`.

I think You have to use this function as:

```
map<int,string> mymap;
//Assume there are some key value pair in above map

void ReturnKey(int &a, string& str)
{
   map<int,string>::iterator iter = mymap.find(a);
    if(iter not_eq mymap.end())
    {
       str = itr->second;        
    }   

}
```

Or you can return `std::string` values for status of your operation.
As follows:

```
 map<int,string> mymap;
    //Assume there are some key value pair in above map

    std::string ReturnKey(int &a)
    {
       std::string ret;
        map<int,string>::iterator iter = mymap.find(a);
        if(iter not_eq mymap.end())
        {
         ret = iter->second;//I think this will make copy
        }
       else{
          delete ret;
          return null;
        }
        return ret;            
    }
```

and `#include <string>` should be used.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Second approach will result in crash.